# Como deserializar JSON com C#

Tags: c#, json, windows

Eu tenho esse JSON

```
[{
"new_as_cod": "0010955",
"as_nome": "NAME",
"as_cpf": "1212121212",
"as_email": "IM@UOL.COM.BR",
"as_cep": "88.025-200",
"igr_nome": "1\u00aa IGREJA BATISTA - FLORIANOPOLIS",
"id": "2781",
"valor": "50.00",
"pg_tipo_id": "CC",
"status": "Ativo",
"idstatus": "1"
}]
```

a classe foi gerada a partir [daqui](http://json2csharp.com)

```
 public class RootObject
{
    public string new_as_cod { get; set; }
    public string as_nome { get; set; }
    public string as_cpf { get; set; }
    public string as_email { get; set; }
    public string as_cep { get; set; }
    public string igr_nome { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public string pg_tipo_id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string idstatus { get; set; }
}
```

Tenho tentado usar essa expressão.

```
RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(stringdate);
as_nome.Text = data.as_nome.ToString();
as_cpf.Text = data.as_cpf.ToString();
```

Mas está dando este erro.

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code Additional information: 
>   Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'HelloWorldWP.MainPage+RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Cara, coloca o texto da exception e não um print dela.

Comment: An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'HelloWorldWP.MainPage+RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Henrique, clique em [edit] para editar a sua pergunta. Você pode tirar a imagem e colocar o texto da exception, veja a resposta do @OnoSendai, ela está correta. Aliás, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Veja o [tour] e visite a [help] para poder entender melhor como funciona o site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seu JSON é uma coleção contendo um item apenas:

```
[{..}]
```

Você deve então deserializá-lo para uma coleção:

```
List<RootObject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(stringdate);
```

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado por responder.

Entendi, então esse tipo de JSON é uma coleção. 
coloquei essa expressão que você me falou

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(stringdate);

continua dando o erro, mas agora nem compila. Não sei se ta faltando algum import. Pois ja coloquei e instalei aquele newtonsoft.json

Comment: Ele é uma coleção quando tem os colchetes `[...]` @HenriqueAlbuquerque

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HelloWorldWP.MainPage.RootObject>' to 'HelloWorldWP.MainPage.RootObject'.

Comment: entendi, ficarei ligado nos tipos de json da proxima vez @jbueno

Comment: @HenriqueAlbuquerque desculpe, meu exemplo continha um erro. Eu corrigi a última linha.

Comment: @OnoSendai eu que peço desculpas por perturbar haha, desculpe, agora que eu entendi que meu JSON é uma lista, na hora de atribuir ele não esta encontrando o as_nome, por exemplo. data.as_nome.ToString();... acho que esta faltando alguma coisa entre a variavel data e o as_nome, ficando dessa forma data.?????.as_nome.ToString();

Comment: @HenriqueAlbuquerque nem estressa, é um prazer ajudar. =) Sua variável `data` agora é uma coleção: Tente, por exemplo, `data[0].as_nome.ToString();` onde zero é o índice do objeto dentro da coleção.

Comment: @OnoSendai GG! rodou legalzinho, valeu mesmo! Estou começando ae com C# e com webservices.

Comment: @HenriqueAlbuquerque legal ler isso! São tecnologias interessantes. Sinta-se à vontade para postar mais perguntas no caso de qualquer dúvida.

Comment: @HenriqueAlbuquerque, JsonConvert faz parte de qual Namespace, não encontrei aqui a ddl nem para referenciar.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza vc tem que ir no nuget packages e proccurar por json.net, apos instalar... using newtonsoft.json.. que aí funciona.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: @OnoSendai , obrigado!